# jquery error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the example bootstrap sortable table code found here:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/sort/

I have the html / css / and jquery in my html, but whenever I load the page I am getting an error in console:
[image]

All the posts about this error I can find online point to jquery being loaded multiple times, but my html file below, only loads jquery once in the header just like bootstrap says to do. What is causing my jquery error preventing the table from being sortable? Thanks

```js
//table sorting
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});

function update_data() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/popularify_updatePage/",
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data) // check out how data is structured

      // Update the coin amount
      $('.popularifyDataDiv').contents()[0].textContent = data
      //data.coins
    }
  })
};

async function myFunction() {
  console.log("myFunction()")

  //make post request to python function
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  var artistURI = document.getElementById("artistURI-input").value;
  console.log("artistURI = ", artistURI)
  let successValue = await makeAjax(artistURI, csrftoken);
  console.log("successValue = ", successValue)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = successValue;

  var jsonData = JSON.parse(successValue)
  console.log(jsonData)
  var numberOfEntries = Object.keys(jsonData.data).length
  console.log(numberOfEntries) // Object.keys(jsonData.data).length)
  console.log("numberOfEntries in popularify data = ", numberOfEntries)

  var table = document.getElementById("displayTable");
  for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfEntries; i++) {
    let successValue2 = addRowToTable("displayTable", jsonData.data[i].popularity, jsonData.data[i].trackName, jsonData.data[i].albumName, jsonData.data[i].artistName)
  }

}

function addRowToTable(tableID, cell1String, cell2String, cell3String, cell4String) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    //add new stuff to row
    var row = table.insertRow(0); //make new row
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //add cells to row
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = cell1String; //add text to cells
    cell2.innerHTML = cell2String;
    cell3.innerHTML = cell3String;
    cell4.innerHTML = cell4String;
    /*
    <th scope="col">Popularity</th>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
    <th scope="col">Album</th>
    <th scope="col">Artist</th>
    */
    resolve("added")
  });


}

function makeAjax(dataVar, csrftoken) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/popularify_py/',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        data: dataVar
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        console.log("ajax success, returning msg = " + msg)
        resolve(msg)
      }
    });
  });
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
```

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
  bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div>
    arthur russell = spotify:artist:3iJJD5v7oIFUevW4N5w5cj <br> pink floyd = spotify:artist:0k17h0D3J5VfsdmQ1iZtE9 <br> the shifts = spotify:artist:4ULme3Xscdg9b0he9bUYc0 <br>
  </div>
  <p>Click the button to call a python function.</p>

  Spotify Artist URI: <input type="text" id="artistURI-input" value=""><button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <!-- //loading gif
<div class="spinner-border" role="status">
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
-->
  <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="th-sm">Name
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Position
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Office
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Age
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Start date
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Salary
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Position
        </th>
        <th>Office
        </th>
        <th>Age
        </th>
        <th>Start date
        </th>
        <th>Salary
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <table class="table table-dark" id=displayTable>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Popularity</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Album</th>
        <th scope="col">Artist</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <p>printing updating json test</p>
  <button onclick="update_data()">popularify_updatePage</button>
  <pre class='popularifyDataDiv'>{{ json_pretty }}</pre>
```

Comment: You didn't include `datatable.js`

Comment: I see in your source code you're loading jquery slim 3.3.1 and I see your error message indicates 3.4.1 loaded from google's CDN. Looks like a "multiple versions of jQuery" problem to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js` which is dataTables library as @Vineesh commented. Check this.

```js
//table sorting
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});

function update_data() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/popularify_updatePage/",
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data) // check out how data is structured

      // Update the coin amount
      $('.popularifyDataDiv').contents()[0].textContent = data
      //data.coins
    }
  })
};

async function myFunction() {
  console.log("myFunction()")

  //make post request to python function
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  var artistURI = document.getElementById("artistURI-input").value;
  console.log("artistURI = ", artistURI)
  let successValue = await makeAjax(artistURI, csrftoken);
  console.log("successValue = ", successValue)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = successValue;

  var jsonData = JSON.parse(successValue)
  console.log(jsonData)
  var numberOfEntries = Object.keys(jsonData.data).length
  console.log(numberOfEntries) // Object.keys(jsonData.data).length)
  console.log("numberOfEntries in popularify data = ", numberOfEntries)

  var table = document.getElementById("displayTable");
  for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfEntries; i++) {
    let successValue2 = addRowToTable("displayTable", jsonData.data[i].popularity, jsonData.data[i].trackName, jsonData.data[i].albumName, jsonData.data[i].artistName)
  }

}

function addRowToTable(tableID, cell1String, cell2String, cell3String, cell4String) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    //add new stuff to row
    var row = table.insertRow(0); //make new row
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //add cells to row
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = cell1String; //add text to cells
    cell2.innerHTML = cell2String;
    cell3.innerHTML = cell3String;
    cell4.innerHTML = cell4String;
    /*
    <th scope="col">Popularity</th>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
    <th scope="col">Album</th>
    <th scope="col">Artist</th>
    */
    resolve("added")
  });


}

function makeAjax(dataVar, csrftoken) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/popularify_py/',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        data: dataVar
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        console.log("ajax success, returning msg = " + msg)
        resolve(msg)
      }
    });
  });
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
```

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
  bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    arthur russell = spotify:artist:3iJJD5v7oIFUevW4N5w5cj <br> pink floyd = spotify:artist:0k17h0D3J5VfsdmQ1iZtE9 <br> the shifts = spotify:artist:4ULme3Xscdg9b0he9bUYc0 <br>
  </div>
  <p>Click the button to call a python function.</p>

  Spotify Artist URI: <input type="text" id="artistURI-input" value=""><button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <!-- //loading gif
<div class="spinner-border" role="status">
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
-->
  <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="th-sm">Name
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Position
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Office
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Age
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Start date
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Salary
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Position
        </th>
        <th>Office
        </th>
        <th>Age
        </th>
        <th>Start date
        </th>
        <th>Salary
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <table class="table table-dark" id=displayTable>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Popularity</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Album</th>
        <th scope="col">Artist</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <p>printing updating json test</p>
  <button onclick="update_data()">popularify_updatePage</button>
  <pre class='popularifyDataDiv'>{{ json_pretty }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have an empty column that is generated based on NULL value. Try to put 'NULL' on the mentioned column.